# React Provider Pattern, prop not updating in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-context

So i have written a provider to pass strings to any part of my application.  The issue i have is that if i add a strings prop to my child component it overrides the entire prop and seems to ignore the merge i do in connector

### Provider

```
import { Component, Children } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default class StringsProvider extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    strings: PropTypes.object
  }

  // Specify what is being added to context
  static childContextTypes = {
    strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  getChildContext() {
    const { strings } = this.props

    return { strings: strings }
  }

  render() {
    return Children.only(this.props.children)
  }
}
```

### Connector

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import _ from 'lodash'

// here we basically create a HOC that returns on Context (This is our component).
// The HOC adds the merged strings set to the Context Component and then renders it
export default (WrappedComp, defaultStrings, stringNameSpace) => {
  return class StringsComponent extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    static contextTypes = {
      strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    // Takes the defaultStrings from the context and merges them with the
    // strings passed to the Context Component
    getStrings = () => {
      let out

      if (this.props.strings) {

        console.log('defaultStrings: ' + Object.values(defaultStrings)[0])
        console.log(
          'this.context.strings[stringNameSpace]: ' +
            Object.values(this.context.strings[stringNameSpace])[0]
        )
        console.log(
          'this.props.strings: ' + Object.values(this.props.strings)[0]
        )
        out = _.merge(
          defaultStrings,
          this.context.strings[stringNameSpace] ? this.context.strings[stringNameSpace] : {},
          this.props.strings
        )
      } else {
        out = _.merge(defaultStrings, this.context.strings[stringNameSpace])
      }


      console.warn('out')
      console.log(out)
      return out
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComp strings={this.getStrings()}  {...this.props} />

    }
  }
}
```

### Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connectStrings } from './../../src'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import defaultStrings from './strings'

class SampleComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    strings: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { strings } = this.props
console.warn(strings)
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{strings.str1}</span>
        <span>{strings.str2}</span>
        <span>{strings.str3}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connectStrings(
  SampleComponent,
  defaultStrings,
  'sampleComponent.ui.SET_TWO'
)
```

### Unit test to run

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import React from 'react'
import { StringProvider } from '../src'
import SampleComponent from "../components/sampleComponent";
describe('String Provider Tests', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const strings = {
      'sampleComponent.ui.SET_ONE': {
        str1: 'SET ONE'
      },
      'sampleComponent.ui.SET_TWO': {
        str1: 'SP Str1',
        str2: 'SP Str2'
      }
    }

    const tree = renderer.create(
      <StringProvider strings={strings}>
        <SampleComponent strings={{str3: 'test'}}/>

      </StringProvider>
    )

    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Im not sure what i am missing here, but strings seems to be updated in the connector but not in the component, is there something im not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

How silly, ht answer was simple, below i just needed to change the order the props were added in the wrapped component

```
return <WrappedComp strings={this.getStrings()}  {...this.props} />
```

It seems that as this.props also contained strings it was overwriting the result of the `GetStrings()` function.